# How do I make NSMetadataQuery see my saved documents' folders as packages?

Tags: icloud, uidocument, info-plist, nsmetadataquery

I'm writing an app which saves and loads documents both locally and on iCloud.  Locally is working fine, but I'm having a problem with iCloud.

The documents are saved as a package - the UIDocument reads and writes an NSFileWrapper which contains an image file, a thumbnail file, and an info plist.  When I save the document to iCloud and then look at the files under 'Manage Storage', I see the individual files instead of the packages; and more importantly when I search for files using NSMetadataQuery it returns an NSMetadataItem for each of the individual files instead of the packages.  As a result, my app doesn't realise there are any packages to load and iCloud is pretty useless.

I *thought* that if I set up the document type and exported the UTI correctly that the packages would be treated properly.  Was that right?  If so, what's the checklist for setting up a document type as a package?  I have:

- Added a document type
- set LSTypeIsPackage to YES (I've tried string YES and bool YES)
- set CFBundleTypeExtensions to an array containing one string: the file suffix
- set LSHandlerRank to Owner
- Exported a UTI with the same identifier
- set it to conform to com.apple.package
- added a UITypeTagSpecification dictionary, containing an array for the key public.filename-extension, which contains one string: the file suffix

I've also tried adding a matching Imported UTI to match the exported one, but no luck there.

What did I miss?

UPDATE: I notice that the OP in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026242/nsmetadataquery-ignoring-custom-file-package-type) is seeing the behaviour I want (even though he doesn't want it) so it must be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg71677.html) I tried removing the LSItemContentTypes from my plist, and it worked.

Comment: wow. I was banging my head on my keyboard for nearly a month over this issue. It clearly seems like a bug. Thanks.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue since yesterday. I am unable to solve this by removing LSItemContentTypes. Please suggest if it can be achieve by any other way. Thanks alot.

Comment: What about the situation, when I need LSItemContentTypes to enable importing files of this filetype to my app?